# How to use multiple languages in one view?

Tags: cakephp

is there a way to use two or more languages in one view using the translation method (double underscore)? something like this:

```
$this->setLanguage("ger");
echo __("Translate me");

$this->setLanguage("fra");
echo __("Translate me");
```

Comment: I think the method I am looking for is __d but it is not working when I try to translate the text:  __d('ger', "Hello World"); it returns "Hello World" and not the translated text.

Comment: That's totally wrong, the "d" stands for domain and is thought to logically group languages into domains. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation about I18n in CakePHP.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)

You'll have to set the active language before each __() call that is supposed to display another language.

The documentation shows this:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra');
```

If you want to avoid typing that all over put it into a helper method where you set the language and then call __().

```
echo $this->I18n->__('fra', 'Your text);
```

By the way, AFAIR the identifier for German is "deu", not "ger".